# MongoDb remove 2 data

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of technicians below. How to remove or pull data in both tasks and reservedDates in one command??

```
db.technicians.find().pretty()
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("592acc916a32c48647427b2f"),
    "firstName" : "Pj",
    "lastName" : "Rizal",
    "tasks" : [
            ObjectId("593435177492fb214c3a8694"),
            ObjectId("5934389179439d2c20f07210"),
    ],
    "reservedDates" : [
            {
                    "date" : "2017-06-29T16:00:00.000Z",
                    "time" : "2017-06-04T07:14:16.130Z",
            },
            {
                    "date" : "2017-06-29T16:00:00.000Z",
                    "time" : "2017-06-04T07:14:16.130Z",
            },
    ]


}
```

Comment: db.technicians.update({}, 
    {$pull: {reservedDates: { date: '2017-06-29T16:00:00.000Z'}}}, 
    {multi: true}

Answer (score 0):

```
db.technicians.update({}, 
    {$pull: {reservedDates: { date: '2017-06-29T16:00:00.000Z'}}}, 
    {multi: true}
```

Comment: Set the multi option so that every document is updated, not just the first one.

Comment: No. "multi" applies to "multiple documents in the collection" as opposed to "one" which is the default. The OP is asking how to remove/pull data from both the `"reservedDates"` and `"tasks"` arrays in a single update statement. There is a specific way to do that. This is not it.

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB documentation

> The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a
>   value or values that match a specified condition.

In above mentioned MongoDB document reservedDates field represents an embedded document .

To remove an entry from an embedded document belonging to a document matching specific condition update operation using $pull operator needs to be executed in MongoDB shell.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It's only a citation from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and commentary on that question. Nothing here addresses the question asked or even attempts to.